# What size backpack do I need for mountaineering expeditions?

Tags: gear, mountaineering, backpacks, alpine

I am trying to decide on a backpack strategy for Himalayan expeditions to 6k-7k peaks. Typically, these involve a few days approach march to the base camp. Then the actual climbing is another 3-5 days from base camp / advance base camp to the summit.

In total, I will need to carry the following -

- Crampons + compatible ice boots
- Ice axes and trekking poles
- Some carabiners, ice screws, pulleys, ascender, descender,
- Shovel
- Snow anchors
- Rope - 40/60m and some cords
- Waist Harness
- Helmet
- 2/3 person tent
- Sleeping bag
- Stove, fuel
- Food
- Water bottle
- Down jacket
- Heavy gloves/mittens
- spare socks, 1 set clothing, inners
- First aid kit
- bivvy / emergency kit
- might have missed something..

How much space (liters) do I need to fit all this?

In general, if we use top of the line products, the weight and volume can be reduced. But for now, let's assume good quality but not *the most expensive* gear.

A rule of thumb I've heard (not verified) is for high altitude expeditions, use a 90 liter pack. Assuming 90 liters is needed, what's a better strategy -

1. A single 90 l pack, or
2. A 60-65 l pack and another 35 l pack. This way, the bigger pack stays at base camp and the smaller 35 l goes up the mountain. Alternatively open the route with the smaller pack and then load ferry the larger pack using fixed ropes.

We could also would hire porters/mules until the base camp  and climb by ourselves (with a guide) beyond that. In this case, it might be easier to load the 65 l pack on the mule and walk with the 35 l pack.

Even when 90 liters has to be carried by oneself, is there an advantage to packing it in two packs - wearing the bigger one on the back and the smaller one on the front? There seems to be [some studies](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30482109/) that distributing the load over the front and back is better.

I would really appreciate from folks experienced in multi-day high altitude expeditions about if my line of reasoning makes sense and what is a good strategy?

Comment: Its not quite clear to me whether the climbing is 3-5 days away from the tent or 3-5 day-trips? What about emergency shelter? What do you need to carry during the climbing? As far as I can tell that list you supplied is a pretty short climbing list for that sort of altitude and you would need to carry or haul it all.

Comment: The list is not meant to be exhaustive, more to get an idea of how much volume of gear to plan for. The summit is 3-5 days of climbing after base camp / advance base camp. So we will need to set up intermediate camps. Just updated the question.

Comment: Won't the boots be on your feet? Ice boots are really bulky if you have to pack them. If you hike in wearing something else (perhaps necessary depending on conditions) your pack will shrink a lot when you swap to the ice boots. That will affect your plan. This sounds like the sort of thing where the group needs to be using the same strategy around what to stash where, and what to carry in the higher stages

Comment: @ChrisH, yes, the approach march will be in Salomons, till base camp. Beyond that, the Salomons take rest, and the hard shell boots come out.

Comment: So I wouldn't want the extra weight and hassle of 2 packs on the hike to base camp, but I'd be looking hard at ways of shrinking the pack at that point. Mountaineering packs tend to be quite good for attaching stuff on the outside after all

Comment: Ok. Would you have any rough guidance on pack volume?

Comment: Packing strategy is something I know a bit about. High altitude mountaineering much less so

Comment: An empty 35 l backpack weighs very little. You can put it inside the big one empty, and then re-pack before the climb. In my experience, 90 l is barely enough for just normal kit and food for some days (ten or so).

Comment: I was just now typing/asking exactly what you (Tomas) wrote... @ChrisH - is this a legit strategy? Pros - 1) if load is much, and we use mules, they can carry the bigger pack, and me the smaller 35L, 2) can be used for the actual climb. Cons - 1) two packs. 2) 35L needs to be packed a little carefully so the curved "airflow" back doesnt get damaged.

Comment: @TomasBy Good to know. Thanks for the estimate. When 90L is insufficient, then we surely hire porters/mules.

Comment: "if... we use mules" is fundamental information you need to find out.

Comment: @TomasBy I haven't got a 35 l but I've got 2 quite substantial 40 l packs and only one of my three 2 25s is really light - the one without a decent back (also the only one that rolls up small). But if you're talking about packing an extra empty 35 l pack inside your main pack, and that main pack needing to be over 90 l anyway, that main pack is going to need to be huge

Comment: Well, I was thinking a simple pack with no frame or anything. The one I have could easily go inside a bigger one and only take up some space (a liter or two perhaps). Or you can strap it on the outside.

Comment: @TomasBy that makes more sense than using a small pack with a frame (though my heavier bulkier 25 just had a lot of padding and straps originally - now it's worse because I've adapted it to work as a bike pannier). But even this day pack should be good to carry for repeated long days.

Comment: I am a bit scared when I read your question. Doing a 6k-7k peak is not like a Sunday afternoon hike, You should not do it unless you did some experience on lower peaks. However, your question looks like you are a beginner, an experienced mountaineer would not ask such a basic question.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks for your concern, appreciated. I have already done 5.5K+ peaks. The pack we used on those was 90L to carry a load of 18-20 kg over 25 km tough terrain to base camp. From base camp to summit, only the technical climbing gear was needed. However, those climbs were organized larger groups by someone else, so I am not too aware of all the specifics / logistical details. Some gear, like ropes, etc. were shared. There were porters for kitchen stuff. This time we're getting our own gear, starting with an easy 6K. The 7K in the title is to make the responses "future-proof".

Comment: If those are the only 2 options, I'd probably go with 60+35 option, get most of your "permament" gear in 60 and 35 for stuff that you going to "spend" so eventually you can just empty it completely. Or as you've mentioned - leaving 60l one in the camp and using smaller one.